# Unable to find source of margin in navbar

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of experience with HTML and CSS and have just started to use flexbox today.

I am attempting to make a simple navbar using flexbox but it has a top and bottom margin of 16px that I cant figure out how it is occurring.

I have tested it on both Firefox and Chrome and get the same results. I have also tried giving the ul.menu a margin of 0 to no effect. I have google and searched here for a solution but was unable to find one.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
* {
    margin: none;
    padding: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

    nav {
        
        background-color: black;
    }
    
    ul { 
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: end;
        align-items: center;
        /* list-style-type: none; */
        margin: none;
    }
    
    ul.menu {
        padding-left: 0rem;
        margin-top: 0%;
    }
    
    a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    
    a:hover {
        color: goldenrod;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    .menu li {
        padding: 1rem;
    }   
    
    .logo   {
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    
    }
    
    .logo img {
    height: 4rem;
    /* width: auto; */
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/navbar.css">   
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <nav>
          <ul class="menu">
          <li class="logo"><a href="/Navbar.html"><img src="/irishlogo.png" alt="24th georgia flag"></a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="**">Event Shedule</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="**">History</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="**">Pics & Vids</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `body`, `ul`, `li` to `margin: 0; padding: 0;` and it should take care of all phantom whitespace.

Comment: In certain browsers there are default values set on body, ul, li and other elements so it's always good idea to reset these global values to zero to prevent any styling "bugs".

Comment: You are awesome! That fixed it. I wondered why my settings on * were not working and now I realise I had set them to none which is not accepted and when I changed it to 0 it had the same effect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the above code for margin: none; padding: none; to margin:0; and padding:0;

Your final code should look like this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you set

```
menu.li { 
  padding: 0px;
}
```

then the padding will remove.